# How to fix USB-connection between Android 11 to Ubuntu 20.04 (to backup phone data - after not properly unmounting)?

Tags: usb, mount, backup, android

I transferred fotos etc from Android 11 (Samsung S10e) to Ubuntu via USB; then, after completion, tried to unmount (I think) which then stalled (if I remember correctly) then pulled the plug and since then I can't properly mount/connect via USB again as before. - Of the USB connection options presented to me by Android, I can now only connect via "**Transferring images**" (also known perhaps as "**PTP via USB turned on**") instead of "**Transferring files**" (which worked before).

How to fix / reset the connection so that also the other connection mode ("Transferring files") will work again as before?

---

- I already rebooted both the phone and the laptop: no change.
- `/var/crash` contains _usr_libexec_gvfsd-mtp.1000.crash

Comment: Have you tried to use `adb-tools`? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1363298/adb-command-not-found-after-installed-it/1363318#1363318

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Media_Transfer_Protocol

Comment: @CrazyTux No... ideally, I wouldn't want to have to install anything other than what's included in standard Ubuntu (20.04); I just need to find a way to cleanly reset the phone's connection. Incidentally, I have the same phoen twice (Samsung S10e) and only one of them has the issue - after messing up the mounting/unplugging some time ago. The other device continues to work normally...

Comment: `/run/user/1000/gvfs$ ls` stays blank, as if it were still waiting for the info to come through; if I then unplug the phone, it says `ls: cannot access 'mtp:host=SAMSUNG_SAMSUNG_Android_R38MB............`

Comment: well i think `adb` is the right tool for that aka Android Debug Bridge, check out this topic it might be helpful https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb

Comment: @CrazyTux OK, is the [link to the zip](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-linux.zip) you provide [in your answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1363318/16023) the most official way to do it, or is there some equivalent in official Ubuntu channels?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/34702/how-do-i-set-up-android-adb seems in need of an update for 2021...

Comment: try to install it by the topic answers, first try `apt install android-tools-adb` (did not worked for me), i installed `adb`  with downloading the zip file like the answer i posted, the link to the zip file in my answer is the official link from the SDK Platform tools website like here https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/platform-tools, here is the best guide i found for adb: https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/

Comment: `sudo apt-get install android-tools-adb` vs. `sudo apt-get install adb`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/130348/discussion-between-crazytux-and-nutty-about-natty).

Comment: Make sure you select the MTP profile for the USB connection on your phone. This can be done by showing notifications and then tapping the USB notification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While [this](https://whoozle.github.io/android-file-transfer-linux/) may be a good solution (which I didn't yet try) a perhaps simpler and reliable solution for me was / is to use a **standard USB flash drive** (and, if needed, a USB-C/A adapter) instead of directly conneting to a PC / Ubuntu; this way, the drive is handled by Android directly and no need to get MTP to work...

---

Further links (including (Samsung-?)related bugs):

- https://sourceforge.net/p/libmtp/bugs/1830/
- https://sourceforge.net/p/libmtp/bugs/1808/
- [Nautilus hangs on accessing DCIM/Camera on Android](https://askubuntu.com/questions/995383/nautilus-hangs-on-accessing-dcim-camera-on-android)
- [Can't open photos stored on Android system from Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1030736/cant-open-photos-stored-on-android-system-from-ubuntu/1148034#1148034)
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Media_Transfer_Protocol

Answer (score 0):

I have problems too with mounting Android 11 (Motorola G20) on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. It only works if I first select on the phone: USB Virtual Drive, which mounts an almost empty CD drive, then select on the phone: MTP, which then succeeds and shows the files from the phone.

Maybe this workaround works also for you.