# adb command not found after installed it

Tags: software-installation, bashrc, adb

I have install adb from terminal. But when I type "adb version" it's not found. Can anyone help me about this problem?

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information. How did you install it

Comment: What is the output of `/usr/lib/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb`

Comment: i have just tried in my own pc again, `cd` into your `platform-tools` directory and then use the `adb` command like a script `./adb <options>`.

Comment: I am installed follow this link
https://medium.com/@petehouston/fix-adb-command-not-found-on-ubuntu-linux-96f6d0dfd70

But it's still not working for me.

Answer (score 5):

Use this command for adb installation:

```
apt install android-tools-adb
```

Comment: Installed successfully. But when I run the command "adb version", it displays the message "command adb not found"

Comment: This should work. Verify that your are not having any other adb package installed before installing this. Do `apt autoremove`. Reboot your system after install.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the Android SDK Platform Tools ZIP file for Linux from this [link](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/platform-tools-latest-linux.zip).
2. Move the file to the location you want to store `adb` using the following command `sudo mv filename.zip /wanted/location/.`
3. Extract the ZIP with `unzip filename.zip` command.
4. Enter to `platform-tools/` directory with `cd platform-tools/`

   - if you are not in the extracted directory use the full PATH `cd /home/user/directory/platform-tools`
5. Now you can use the `adb` tool from inside the `platform-tools` directory using `./adb [options]` for example `./adb version`.

- This solution is given from XDA-DEVELOPERS forum.
- For more information you can look in the original manual on this [link](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/amp/)

Comment: Thanks it works for me! :)